# NoReverseMatch at /add/

Tags: python, django

I keep getting error on my url tag. The syntax is right and i tried different solution that is asked on SO but no luck yet.

**my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', LandingView.as_view(), name="landing_page"),
    url(r'^add/$', AddView.as_view(), name="add"),
    url(r'^rent/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', rent_detail, name="rent_detail"),
    url(r'^add/space/$', AddSpaceView.as_view(), name="addSpace"),
    url(r'^lang/$', Language.as_view(), name="lang"),
    url(r'^upload/image/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ImageUpload, name="ImageUpload"),
    url(r'^filter/space/$', FilterSpace.as_view(), name="filterSpace"),
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def ImageUpload(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        rental = Rental.objects.get(pk = kwargs.get('pk'))
    except Rental.DoesNotExist:
        error_dict = {'message': 'Rental spae not found'}
        return self.render(request,'rentals/add.html',error_dict)
    for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
        image = GalleryImage.objects.create(image=file,rental=rental)
    response_dict = {
        'message': 'File Uploaded Successfully'
    }
    context = {
        'rental':rental
    }
    return self.render(request,'rentals/add.html',context)

class AddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'rentals/add.html'
```

**add.html**

```
<div id="listing">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // want to passs url for uploading image in ajax url parameter
    var data = {
        urltag: "{% url 'ImageUpload' rental.id %}"
    }

    console.log('url is', data); 
    $(function() {
      app.showListingSpaceForm("listing",data);
    });

</script>
```

ajax for uploading image

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"/upload/image/", // upload form is in add.html which is developed using frontend library reactjs and i need to pass id here so that the image will be saved to its associated rent.
        data:image,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        type:'POST',
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('success');
        }
       });
    }
```

**Update: Ajax code where i want id in url for uploading image to its associated rent**

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /add/
Reverse for 'ImageUpload' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['upload/image/(?P<pk>\\d+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'upload/image/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Comment: I have update with AddView and reason why i want id in add.html page.

Comment: I want rental.id in ajax code that is in add.html template. My add.html renders a listing form that is developed uisng reactjs . There is <div id="listing">
 </div> html tag which has frontend form and that ajax code.So id is needed in add.html page where there is form and ajax code for sending image to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to `/add/`, Django will run `AddView` because you have a url pattern.

```
url(r'^add/$', AddView.as_view(), name="add"),
```

That view will render `rentals/add.html`, because you have:

```
class AddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'rentals/add.html'
```

Rendering the template will fail, because you are using `rental` in the url tag, but you have not defined rental anywhere.

```
{% url 'ImageUpload' rental.id %}
```

Unless your `AddView` can set `rental` in the template context, then using the url tag like this will not work.

Comment: I think i have to do this then and can fetch id class AddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'rentals/add.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rental'] = Rental.objects.all()
        return context

Comment: My main requirement is to save image to its associated rent. I could upload images but they are not saved to their associated rent. I have to manually add images to their rent from admin .

Comment: Overriding `get_context_data` like that will pass *all* rentals to the template context. The url tag still won't work, unless it's inside a loop like `{% for rental in rentals %}{% url 'ImageUpload' rental.id %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Yes that way I got multiple IDs .

Comment: Sorry I have deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly pass down the kwarg argument since you defined it in your urls.py :

```
var data = {
    urltag: "{% url 'ImageUpload' pk=rental.id %}"
}
```

Comment: Changing `rental` from an arg to a kwarg isn't going to help here.

Comment: I am still gettting an error . Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'ImageUpload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['upload/image/(?P<pk>\\d+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'upload/image/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Comment: This is not true, arguments for named capture groups can be passed as positional arguments to both `reverse()` and `{% url %}`. There's no difference in behaviour between your code and the original code.